# ¿Cómo comprobamos si varios elementos de una array bidimensional son iguales en java sin usar .equals?

Tags: java

Llevo 1 mes en esto de la programación y me encuentro ante este problema. Estoy realizando un programa en **java** que me imprima un `array` bidimensional con elementos aleatorios de manera que no haya 3 o más elementos iguales formando una columna. Mi idea era comparar las coordenadas y en caso de que existan 3 o más iguales formando columna (si forman fila no importa, solo columna), me imprima otra con las mismas condiciones. La cosa es que creo un bucle pero no consigo darle las coordenadas adecuadas a comparar. No sé si no estoy acertado en mi pensamiento o estoy cerca pero no doy con la clave. Gracias de antemano.

Estos son los metodos de mi programa:

```
public static void imprime_matrix(int[][]matrix) {
    for(int i=1;i < matrix.length-1; i++) {
        System.out.println();
        for(int j=1; j < matrix[i].length-1 ; j++) {

            System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + " ");
        }
    }
}

public static int numero_aleatorio(int dificultad) {
    int x=(int)Math.round((Math.random())*10);
    boolean sal_bucle=true;
    while(sal_bucle) {
        if(x==0||x>dificultad) {
            x=(int)Math.round((Math.random())*10);
        }else {
            sal_bucle=false; 
        }
    }
    return x;
}

public static int [][] RellenaMatriz(int dificultad,int NUMERO_DE_FILAS,int NUMERO_DE_COLUMNAS){
    int [][] matrix = new int [NUMERO_DE_FILAS][NUMERO_DE_COLUMNAS];
    for(int i=1; i<matrix.length-1; i++) {
        for(int j=1; j<matrix[i].length-1; j++) {
            matrix[i][j]=numero_aleatorio(dificultad);
        }
    }
    for (int i=0; i<matrix.length;i++) {
        matrix[i][0]=-1;
        matrix[i][10]=-1;
        matrix[0][i]=-1;
        matrix[10][i]=-1;


    }
    return matrix;

}
```

El programa final viene a ser un Candy Crush, de manera que elimine elementos del array si se juntan 3 o más iguales en columna, lo que llamamos "bloques". Para empezar a jugar debo crear una matriz aleatoria de 9x9 pero que no tenga bloques. Mi problema reside en que no hallo la forma de comprobar que no haya elementos formando bloques. No se si debo crear un método distinto para ello o incluir el comando en uno de los métodos ya creados

Comment: Hola @AgapitoDiSousa. Bienvenido a [es.so]. La idea de las preguntas es que sean bien específicas. Lo que creo que deberías hacer es: agregar el código que hiciste, poner un ejemplo de datos y mostrar específicamente en qué está fallando, o dónde estás teniendo problemas. El botón para [edit] está al pie de tu pregunta. Si te interesa, podés leer consejos de cómo crear un [mcve].

Comment: hola, pon un poco de código

Answer (score 2):

La verdad no es tarea fácil si uno toma las riendas por su cuenta, te diría que lo intentes de **maneras más manuales** para practicar, como **iterar** sobre **cada una** de las **dimensiones** del **array** e ir **comparandolas entre sí**.

Sin embargo te voy a dejar un **método** que devuelve un **boolean**, no es muy conocido pero que **puede comparar la equidad dos arrays en su totalidad**, y **si encuentra algún cambio** cualquiera tira **false** y sino **true**.

**deppEquals();**

Creá una clase llamada **Panel** y dale **"Run as java application"**, y fijáte qué te aparece por consola si cambiás algún elemento de los dos arrays.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Panel {

    public void arrayBidimensionalComparator() {
        String array1[][] = {
                {"item1", "1" },
                {"item2", "2" },
                {"item3", "3" },
                {"item4", "4" },
                {"item5", "5" },
                {"item6", "6" },
                {"item7", "7" }
            };

        String array2[][] = {
                {"item1", "1" },
                {"item2", "2" },
                {"item3", "3" },
                {"item4", "4" },
                {"item5", "5" },
                {"item6", "6" },
                {"item7", "7" }
            };

        boolean comparador = Arrays.deepEquals(array1, array2);
        System.out.println(comparador);
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Panel p = new Panel();
        p.arrayBidimensionalComparator();
    }

}
```

En este caso devuelve **true**, porque **son absolutamente iguales**.

ahora **vamos** a hacerlo **devolver** **false**.

```
    import java.util.Arrays;

public class Panel {

    public void arrayBidimensionalComparator() {
        String array1[][] = {
                {"item1", "5" },
                {"item2", "4" },
                {"item3", "1" },
                {"item4", "6" },
                {"item5", "8" },
                {"item6", "9" },
                {"item7", "2" }
            };

        String array2[][] = {
                {"item1", "1" },
                {"item2", "2" },
                {"item3", "3" },
                {"item4", "4" },
                {"item5", "5" },
                {"item6", "6" },
                {"item7", "7" }
            };

        boolean comparador = Arrays.deepEquals(array1, array2);
        System.out.println(comparador);
    }

}
```

Lo único que **hicimos** fue cambiar **el contenido** de los **arrays** y el método compara si hay algún cambio, en este caso **como hay un cambio** devuelve **false**.

**Otra opción**, pero **"en este caso se compara una fila del array bidimensional"** y **devuelve** el **resultado** de **la segunda fila**, sin embargo **en este caso sólo** se compara toda **una columna** con **un sólo objeto predefinido**.

Ahora te voy a pasar un **código anexo nomás** por si te ayuda con **la búsqueda de tu respuesta** y para que lo modifiques como te parezca **así llegas a conseguir la comparación** entre dos bidimensionales.

El siguiente código **lee la primer columna del bidireccional** y lo **compara** con **un sólo String**, devolviendo la segunda columna del objeto igual.

```
public class Panel {

    public String arrayBidimensionalComparador() {

        String result = null;

        String array[][] = {
                {"item1", "1"},
                {"item2", "2"},
                {"item3", "3"},
                {"item4", "4"},
                {"item5", "5"},
                {"item6", "6"},
                {"item7", "7"}
            };

            String pivote = "item5";

            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                if (pivote.equals(array[i][0])) {
                    result = array[i][1]; 

                }
            }
            return result;
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Panel p = new Panel();
        System.out.println(p.arrayBidimensionalComparador());
    }

}
```

Te va a sar el mismo resultado en este caso si utilizás el comparador **==**, sólo tenes que **cambiar** el método **equals()** por **==**, sin embargo esto es sólo orientativo, si querés saber bien la diferencia fijate que está lleno de preguntas y respuestas al respecto.

```
public class Panel {

    public String arrayBidimensionalComparador() {

        String result = null;

        String array[][] = {
                {"item1", "1"},
                {"item2", "2"},
                {"item3", "3"},
                {"item4", "4"},
                {"item5", "5"},
                {"item6", "6"},
                {"item7", "7"}
            };

            String pivote = "item5";

            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                if (pivote == array[i][0]) {
                    result = array[i][1]; 

                }
            }
            return result;
    }
```

Y para finalizar te dejo algo más manual, donde se compara algunos String que están dentro del array y devuelve el número de la derecha, la contra de este código es que no hice una iteración, sino que coloqué un if() donde compara individualmente los objetos que le indiqué.

```
public class Panel {

    public void arrayBidimensionalComparador() {


        String array[][] = {
                {"item1", "1"}, // Posición 0 
                {"item2", "2"},
                {"item3", "3"}, // Posición 2 
                {"item4", "4"},
                {"item5", "5"},
                {"item6", "6"}, // Posición 5 
                {"item7", "7"}
            };

            String pivote1 = array[0][0];
            String pivote2 = array[2][0];
            String pivote3 = array[5][0];

            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                if (pivote1.equals(array[i][0])) {
                   System.out.println(array[i][1]); 

                }

                if (pivote2.equals(array[i][0])) {
                    System.out.println(array[i][1]); 

                }

                if (pivote3.equals(array[i][0])) {
                    System.out.println(array[i][1]);

                } 
            }

    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Panel p = new Panel();
       p.arrayBidimensionalComparador();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pienso que puedes incluirlo en el llenado de la matriz, aprovechando que lo haces secuencialmente.

Por ejemplo empiezas a llenar y a partir de la tercera columna ( 1era condición) empiezas a comprobrar.

verificas que el numero de arriba sea igual (segunda condicion)
de ser así verificas que el que esta dos espacios mas arriba sea igual (tercera condición) entonces alli llamas de nuevo a *numero_aleatorio* para traer otro diferente.

El codigo podria ser algo así

```
public static int [][] RellenaMatriz(int dificultad,int NUMERO_DE_FILAS,int NUMERO_DE_COLUMNAS){
    int [][] matrix = new int [NUMERO_DE_FILAS][NUMERO_DE_COLUMNAS];
    for(int i=1; i<matrix.length-1; i++) {
        for(int j=1; j<matrix[i].length-1; j++) {
            do
            {
                matrix[i][j]=numero_aleatorio(dificultad);
            }while( i>=3 && matrix[i][j] == matrix[i-1][j] && matrix[i][j]==matrix[i-2][j]);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Creo que la posible solución pasa por un método como este:

```
public static void Bloque3Items(int examinaCol, int[][]matrix) {

    for(int i=1; i < matrix.length-1; i++) {
        // Comprobamos el elemento anterior y posterior, si son iguales
        // devolvemos la corrdenada de fila actual.
        if ((matrix[i][examinaCol] == matrix[i-1][examinaCol])
            if ((matrix[i][examinaCol] == matrix[i+1][examinaCol]) 
                 return i;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

El método de arriba nos devolverá la coordenada central del un bloque consecutivo de tres elementos iguales de la matriz en una columna o bien un cero si no encuentra ninguno.

Ya sólo resta llamar al método: si devuelve cero no existen bloques de tres iguales consecutivos y si devuelve distinto de cero es que encontró uno. Aquí un ejemplo para la columna 5 de cómo actuar y llamar al método anterior Bloque3Item(.,.):

```
int index = Bloque3Item(5, matrix);

if (index != 0) 
{
    // Genero Número aleatorio para los tres elementos
    // o si se prefiere se puede hacer sólo para el
    // central que rompe igualmente la igualdad.
    matrix[index - 1][5] = numero_aleatorio(dificultad);
    matrix[index + 0][5] = numero_aleatorio(dificultad);
    matrix[index + 1][5] = numero_aleatorio(dificultad);
}
```

Ahora habría que asegurarse que nuestro código no vuelve a generar otro bloque de tres elementos iguales consecutivos tras la nueva generación de valores. Yo lo haría así:

```
public static void AsegurarNoHayBloque3Items(int examinaCol, int[][]matrix) {
    do {
        int index = Bloque3Item(examinaCol, matrix);

        if (index != 0) 
        {
            // Genero Número aleatorio para los tres elementos
            matrix[index - 1][examinaCol] = numero_aleatorio(dificultad);
            matrix[index + 0][examinaCol] = numero_aleatorio(dificultad);
            matrix[index + 1][examinaCol] = numero_aleatorio(dificultad);
        } 

    } while (index != 0);
 }
```

Otra solución más simple y eficaz sería modificar el método donde rellenas la matriz de números aleatorios de esta forma:

```
public static int [][] RellenaMatrizMejorada(int dificultad,int NUMERO_DE_FILAS,int NUMERO_DE_COLUMNAS)
{
    int [][] matrix = new int [NUMERO_DE_FILAS][NUMERO_DE_COLUMNAS];
    for(int i=0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
            int NumRND = numero_aleatorio(dificultad);
            if (i > 0)
            {
                while (matrix[i-1][j] == NumRND) {
                    NumRND = numero_aleatorio(dificultad);   
                }
            }
            // Garantizado NumRND no es igual que su superior
            // por lo que garantizamos que no hayan bloques
            // de tres elementos consecutivos.
            matrix[i][j]= NumRND;
        }
    }

    return matrix;
}
```

Únicamente con el método superior te ahorras unas cuantas de líneas de código y garantizas que no habrá bloques de tres elementos consecutivos. No entiendo la funcionalidad del -1 que metes alrededor de la matriz, yo lo he omitido en los ejemplos.
El método RellenaMatrizMejorada(..) te permite rellanar la matriz ya cumpliendo con la necesidad de que no haya bloques de 3 elementos consecutivos iguales; si se quisiera permitir al menos que pudiera aparecer dos bloques consecutivos basta con variar la condición i > 0 a i > 1, y en la condición while sustituir i-1 por i-2.